# Flex 4 - Expand Children of a Tree with Non-XML Data Provider

Tags: actionscript-3, tree, flex4

I have a tree using an ArrayCollection/Object data provider. The following code worked with an XML data provider but won't work with the non-XML data provider:

`for (var i:int = 0; i < tree.dataProvider.length; i ++){
          tree.expandChildrenOf(tree.dataProvider[i], true);
}`

How can I modify this code to work with the non-xml data provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Some other code changed, and I needed to use callLater().